# how to solve : failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, api, fopen, yahoo

i am using yahoo finance API where i call an API and that gives me a CSV file. below are my codes.

```
$handle = fopen('http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=INFY&f=l1c1va2xj1b4j4dyekjm3m4rr5p5p6s7n=.csv', "r");
```

while execute this line it throws an warning that is

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

i have spend more time on google but no result yet.

but sometimes its working fine without throwing any warning.

another things it also working fine in local. there is no working throw while execute

if anyone knows the exact solution please help me.

Thanks
Sanjib

Comment: because it's a downloadable csv file. after download only you can do any file operation.

Comment: @Ak-Sonu yes i know but it was working fine before 1month without throwing any waning.

Comment: Check you query string. Your `f` parameter seems to be terminated weirdly. Have you looked at https://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvQuotesDownload ?